# Is there an issue with having a weapon that banes specific types of humanoids?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

The bane rune is an uncommon rune that let you deal extra damage to creatures with a specific trait. There is a standard list of traits you could choose, plus this mention:

> The GM might allow bane runes for other creature traits, such as astral, dream, or demon. However, humanoids, undead, and specific types of humanoids (such as elves) are never a valid option.

What problems could emerge from having my game featuring, let's say Orcrist the goblin-bane sword? I don't really see one, besides perhaps a balance issue, but the way this line is added makes me think it is supposed to be somehow important.

Answer (score 9):

### There is no issue, if the bane creatures are uncommon

Overall, if the share of opponents that are affected by bane in your campaign is somewhere in the 10-20% range, then, based on the price of comprable features, and on how common creature types are in published campaigns, allowing humanoid subraces for bane. should not be unbalanced.

If this would be unbalancing will entirely depend on your campaign. The larger a share of combat encounters are against that creature type, the more powerful it is. The fewer hit points most of these opponents have, the more powerful it is. If youre entire campaign is centered around defeating the orcs, than a bane weapon against orcs is way more powerful than what normally could be expected.

#### Price of bane compared to other runes

For comparison, runes like [Flaming](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=295) that always deal +1d6 extra damage baseline cost 500 gp, instead of the 100 gp of Bane. (They have some other extra benefits, mostly more damage on a critical, but they also are subject to resistance and immunity). So, at the current price, if it would affect most of the opponents, it would be too cheap to be balanced. Based on price, it should at best affect 20% of the opponents.

#### Feature impact

Bane adds a fixed amount of +1d6 to damage, no matter how much damage you otherwise deal, or how much hit points the target has. This means, bane is relatively stronger the fewer hit points the monster has. For a starting character fighting goblin warriors (typcially 6 hp), combined with the normal weapon damage and the damage bonus of the character, bane can help to kill these foes with one strike in nearly all cases. For a high level fighter battling an adult dragon with 100s of hit points, bane does very little.

This by itself however can not be the reason to omit Undead or Humanoids and humanoid sub-races, because bane against animals is allowed, and many mundane animals also have only a few hit points.

#### Commonality of opponents

I suspect the main reason for this guideline is that humanoids like goblins or human bandits, or undead like skeletons and zombies are very common in many published adventures especially at lower levels, where bane has most impact. Animals like wolves are also common, but because they are less intelligent, they tend to be less useful tools for the DM and to make up a much smaller share of opponents.

Under this assumption, these types are excluded, because allowing them would make the rune applicable in too many fights, and too powerful for its price.

Here are [statistics for a large number of Pathfinder 2 adventure paths](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder2e/comments/10eo11g/encounter_analysis_of_paizos_adventures/): out of 1814 encounters there, Animals make the largest eligible monster type category with 158, or about 9%. The excluded Humanoids make up the lagest bucket overall with 527, or 29%, Undead the second largest with 256 or 14%.

I think this can provide some guidance that it should be OK to have about 10% of the opponents being vulnerable to bane weapons, without the rune being too powerful, even if these opponents were of a humanoid subrace.

#### Different monsters by type don't matter

How common the different [creature type traits](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx) are by count of creatures with that trait in the rules does not translate 1:1 into how often they show up in your campaign, or published adventures, which is what matters. Here are some example counts:

| Type | Count | Bane? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Animal | 245 | Yes |
| Fungus<sup>1</sup> & Plant | 21+54=75 | Yes |
| Ooze | 33 | Yes |
| Dream | 12 | Optional Example |
| Etheral | 4 | Optional |
| Time | 7 | Optional |
| Humanoid | 255 | No |
| Undead | 236 | No |
| Elf | 7 | No |
| Goblin | 10 | No |
| Orc | 4 | No |

From this it is clear that the rule cannot be based on the number of monsters of a given type. The types that are allowed out of the box range from 245 for the largest category, to 33 for the smallest (e.g. Ooze), and optional extensions go down to allow a single creature (Petitioner) per type.

Both Humanoid and Undead are comparable in count to Animal, which is allowed. Goblin, Elf or Orc are comparable in count to Dream, Time or Ethereal, which are likewise allowed. So the size of categories has no bearing on this criterion.

#### P.S. Bane and literature archetypes

You cite the classic example from Lord of the Rings, *Orcrist*. The most common monsters faced in that setting will be varieties of orcs or goblins (which in Middle Earth are essentially different names for the same race). Having the *effect* of bane on a blade in that world is very powerful, and indeed, Orcrist is a legendary sword. Bane as a cheap and easily obtained enchantment appears not to be a good fit for this. It would make more sense to implement this in a way that needed some "greater bane", if you so want, more powerful and costly.

There are other examples like the black arrow that is used to slay Smaug in the same story, or the special knifes created to kill ring-wraiths. It is evident these weapons kill powerful, rare creatures with a single strike, and the paltry +1d6 in damage from bane as a mechanical implementation would not be a good fit to what they do, either.

---

<sup>1</sup> I inlcuded fungus hazards along with monsters, as they share the type and also tend to have AC and hp, so it should be able to attack and hit them.

Comment: Your section on Different Monsters by Type isn't really constructive; creatures that are humanoid in nature are much more likely to have custom stat blocks to meet a GM's need for specific NPC's compared to 'monsters' who (usually) do what they say regardless of their background

Answer (score 1):

### There's little balancing trouble

A bane weapon only gives its bane-bonus against the target creature type. Including a Bane weapon is generally no issue at all:

- If no enemies of the type appear, the weapon's bane rune is essentially wasted, very much akin to a ranger's favorite enemy if that type never shows up.
- If the enemy type only shows up occasionally, it can make those encounters faster to overcome.
- If the only enemy type is that enemy type, then the weapon constantly is to be treated with the damage of the bane rune.

As long as you mix up your enemy types, the Bane weapon might handle quite neatly - just remember that against those enemies the damage output is a little higher.

### It can appear racist

The trouble is that bane on humanoids instantly appears targeted against such other humanoid species and will appear racist. Would **you** want a sword that thirsts for the blood of the friendly orc barkeeper or elven hunter? If your world is ok with fantasy racism, it is your prerogative as a GM to cut that particular part of the rule.

Comment: Hang on. It’s racist to target sentient life so long as they have two arms, two legs, and a head but not racist if they don’t?

Comment: It's racist to target Orcs, Elves, or Humans.

Comment: My first guess is also that the parallels with racism are why bane doesn't work on specific types of humanoids, but is there any actual evidence to back up this answer?

Comment: @Ruse Bane (Orc) et al. existed in PF1, together with a ranger feature Favored Enemy. The Rule to not allow humanoid subtypes for "Bane" was added in the transition to PF2. I do **not** allege that racism was the reason that it was removed, but I point out that allowing "Bane (Elf)" will include fantasy racism, which is a point the GM has to consider.

Comment: @Trish but not dragons or beholders? I’m not seeing a distinction that you clearly are. What is it?

Comment: @DaleM I'm with you, I'd consider any targeting of a specific sentient species (as opposed to individuals, because you know, murderers and wars) to be chauvinistic - though not racist. Racist would be a non-Drow Elf wielding a Drow Bane Weapon.

Comment: @From which is *exactly* what OP is proposing

Comment: @Trish Yes, a "Non-Drow Elf" as in "Elf which is not a Drow" creating (not using, I'm correcting myself here) a Drow Bane Weapon would be a racist Elf. I think Dale is proposing (which is what I'm agreeing with) that a human creating an Elf or Drow Bane Weapon would be a human chauvinist, not a racist, which would hold true if the if the human created a Dragon Bane Weapon as well, but not for a Animal Bane Weapon, since Animals are not sentient, and probably not for a Beast Bane Weapon, since many/most Beasts are not sentient.

Comment: @From You mean intelligent, instead of sentient, I guess? Sentience is the capability of beings to experience feelings snd sensations, animals are quite capable of it. The Wikipedia article on it has a cat cozying up to a human leg as its top picture

Comment: @From Specicist technically, but Pathfinder calls Elf a *race*.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin It used to be sentient, I guess now it's sapient. Semantics. In D&D, it's easier - if there is possibility of communication and agreements, an individual is obviously something to be evaluated based on their actions rather than their species, whereas a bear is always best left alone, because they have the right to bear arms.